# Errors in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, web-scraping

when the web driver (Chrome) cyclically crawls pages, such errors periodically pop up.
running on a vps under Debian:

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=42815): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /session/db4b551e4339171e038c3048a73f6036/window (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7fbe18da04a8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused'))

and

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='name']"}   (Session info:
> headless chrome=92.0.4515.131)

and under MacOs:

> Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process
> started from chrome location /Applications/Google
> Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome is no longer running, so
> ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

here my settings:

> options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
> options.add_argument('--headless')
> options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
> options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",
> ['enable-automation'])
> options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
> options.add_argument('--disable-notifications') options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
> options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
> options.add_argument('--disable-dev-sh-usage')
> options.add_argument(f'window-size={resol}')

what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run headless in MacOS, because you need an X-window system, but it will work on Linux.
You get more information about this error if you use pyvirtualdisplay (i.e try to install Xvfb to run headless on MacOS).
I run headless in Ubuntu (another Debian):

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0) # visible=0 equiv to headless
display.start()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-sh-usage')
options.add_argument(f'window-size={resol}')
webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path="./chromedriver")
```

Comment: after connecting the display, it stopped working at all:  start error <EasyProcess cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-help'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-help'] oserror=[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Xvfb' return_code=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout_happened=False>

Comment: Are you trying to run it in MacOS? it won't run in MacOS if you use visible=0 (or --headless)

Comment: Do you have the `Xvfb` package installed? I run `dpkg -l | grep xvfb` and the system returns:
`ii  xvfb                                                        2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1~20.04.2            amd64        Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server`, so I have it installed. 
You can install it by running `sudo apt install xvfb` and you can learn about it before installing it with `apt show xvfb`

Comment: here is the solution in my case
# installing the package
apt-get install -y xvfb

# setting the display variable
export DISPLAY=:0

# running the Xvfb server in the background (once)
/usr/bin/Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &

# wait a bit to let it start (once)
sleep 5

# add the prefix "xvfb-run" to the "node " or" python " script
xvfb-run node myscript.js
# or
xvfb-run python myscript.py